# How to alter user input?

Tags: python, string

So atm I'm making a table in python, and for it, I need the user to supply a name of a person for the table (e.g. David Beckham). However when the user has entered this and the table appears, the name needs to look like this: `Beckham, David`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Posting your code this far would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the input in a variable:

```
name = input()

first_name, last_name = name.split(" ")

table_value = last_name + ", " + first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.6+ you can use formatted string literals ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)). You can use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with `maxsplit=1` to account for middle names:

```
x = 'David Robert Bekham'

first_names, last_name = x.rsplit(maxsplit=1)

res = f'{last_name}, {first_names}'

# 'Bekham, David Robert'
```